# Django unique "username" when using local user authentication and "Django Social auth" application

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am using Django local user registration as well as some social media authentication using Django-social_auth webapp. When I go to user table to check the usernames, It looks to me that Django might compromise the uniqueness of the username. For example, if i have two emails "abcdef@gmail.com" and "abcdef@yahoo.com" how would it store such things in the user table as it stores "abcdef" part in the username column.

Comment: Where’s your code? Need to see the model. Try `unique_together` ?

Comment: I think you need to write custom pipeline. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

`python-social-auth` will attempt to build a unique username when a collision is detected, relevant code is [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/1d809941ab8a99af9e1bdf12bae548202c94eaa2/social_core/pipeline/user.py#L55-L58).

There are also options to "cleanup" a username by defining the [`SOCIAL_AUTH_CLEAN_USERNAME_FUNCTION`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/1d809941ab8a99af9e1bdf12bae548202c94eaa2/social_core/pipeline/user.py#L22).

And you can also define your custom `get_username` pipeline function that can fit better on your project.